# Jquery passing string to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the name of my list into my function, but it's not working correctly. I am trying to pass an array and a string to my function. I want to replace "#myGallery_2" to be dynamic. How would I do this correctly? This is what i'm currently trying.

```
var src = $('#'+id+ li:nth-child('+index+')')

<ul id="myGallery_2">
<li></li>
<li>
</ul>
```

---

```
var images= [
    'IMG_3872_s.jpg',
    'IMG_3926_s.jpg',
    'IMG_3929_s.jpg',
    'IMG_3930_s.jpg'
         ];  




$('#menu li:nth-child(2)').click(function(){
addThumbs(images, '#myGallery_2');
});
```

---

### Function

```
function addThumbs(paths,id) {

        $.each(paths,function(index, value) {
        var str = value; 
        var big_img=str.replace("_s","_b");
        var src = $('#myGallery_2 li:nth-child('+index+')').find('img').attr('data-frame', value);
        var src = $('#myGallery_2 li:nth-child('+index+')').find('img').attr('src', big_img);
        });
```

Comment: You have an odd number of quotes in the line `var src=...`.

Comment: Is the element not being found correctly or is there a javascript error? You can verify whether the element exists by using the length attribute.

Comment: There are typos in the code you posted. Is that an extra `<li>` without an end tag? Also, try debugging your code using Firebug or the WebKit inspector to see why things are not working.

Comment: And you declare and assign `src` twice.

Comment: Another tip: Think about why you need `'#'` in the first line if you are already calling the function with `'#myGallery_2'`.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle with what you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: fix quotes

```
var src = $('#' + id + ' li:nth-child(' + index + ')')
```